# null pointer exception in song manager?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying this code for geting a playlist.

```
final String MEDIA_PATH=new String(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+"!=0");  
    //final String MEDIA_PATH=new String(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PRIVATE);
            private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 & .mp4 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP4"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat --

```
02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389): at com.example.androidtablayout.SongsManager.getPlayList(SongsManager.java:29) 
02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389): at com.example.androidtablayout.AudioActivity.onCreate(AudioActivity.java:29) 
02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

---

i am using your code Grishu as u suggest but in this again error come the way i use it shown below:

```
public class SongsManager {
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private Cursor musiccursor, videocursor;
// projection for audio media files
    String[] music = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
    // projection for video media files
    String[] video = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };

    int totalSongs,totalSongs1;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>getPlayList(){
        // set cursor for audio media
        musiccursor= managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                music, null, null, null);
        // set cursor for video media
        videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                video, null, null, null);

        totalSongs=musiccursor.getCount();
        totalSongs1=videocursor.getColumnCount();

         if (musiccursor!= null) {
                if (musiccursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String songname = musiccursor.getString(musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        int song_id = musiccursor.getInt(musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                        String fullpath = musiccursor.getString(musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                        songsList.addAll(songsList);
                        String albumname =musiccursor.getString(musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                        int album_id = musiccursor.getInt(musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                        String artistname = musiccursor.getString(musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                        int artist_id = musiccursor.getInt(musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));

                     } while (musiccursor.moveToNext());
                }
                musiccursor.close();
            }
         else if (videocursor!=null) {
            if(videocursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    String songname= videocursor.getString(videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    int song_id= videocursor.getInt(videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
                    String fullpath=videocursor.getString(videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));

                    songsList.addAll(songsList);
                    String albumname =videocursor.getString(videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.ALBUM));
                   // int album_id = videocursor.getInt(videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                    String artistname = videocursor.getString(videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST));
                   // int artist_id = videocursor.getInt(videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST_ID));

                }while (videocursor.moveToNext());
            }
            videocursor.close();
        }
         return songsList;
}


    private Cursor managedQuery(Uri externalContentUri, String[] audio2,
            Object object, Object object2, Object object3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

      }
```

Comment: Post your logcat please.

Comment: 02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at com.example.androidtablayout.SongsManager.getPlayList(SongsManager.java:29)
02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at com.example.androidtablayout.AudioActivity.onCreate(AudioActivity.java:29)
02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-09 10:09:34.749: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Comment: From the line `at com.example.androidtablayout.AudioActivity.onCreate(AudioActivity.java:29)` it shows that its an error on `onCreate` method. Something you have not initialized.

Comment: public class AudioActivity extends ListActivity {
 
 // Songs list
  public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.audio_layout);
        
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

  SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
  // get all songs from sdcard
  this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

Comment: which line is `SongsManager.java:29`?

Comment: Try editing your question instead of pasting code into comments.  I added your logcat for you already.

Comment: above this audio activity can you plz help me to resolve this problem :)

Comment: SongsManager.java:29 this is a line in which i get a prob.

 if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0)

Comment: @user1989314 You are trying to do too much in a single line of code. You have two possibilities for the NPE: 1) `home` is `null` and 2) `listFiles()` returns `null`. You should split up this line into several lines so you can track down which of these causes the error.

Comment: Also note that setting the return value of `listFiles()` to a variable will reduce the number of times that you need to call it and presumably reduce the amount of work your app does by not recreating the list of files a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> ```
>  String[] STAR = { "*" };
>    int totalSongs;
>  public void ListAllSongs() 
>   {
>     Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
>     String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
>     if (MusicUtils.isSdPresent()) {
>         cursor = managedQuery(allsongsuri, STAR, selection, null, null);
>         totalSongs = cursor.getCount();
>         if (cursor != null) {
>             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
>                 do {
>                     String songname = cursor
>                             .getString(cursor                                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
>                     int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
>                             .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
>                     String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor
>                             .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
>                     fullsongpath.add(fullpath);
>                     String albumname = cursor.getString(cursor
>                             .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
>                     int album_id = cursor
>                             .getInt(cursor
>                                     .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
>                     String artistname = cursor.getString(cursor
>                             .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
>                     int artist_id = cursor
>                             .getInt(cursor
>                                     .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));
>                                             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
>             }
>             cursor.close();
>         }
>     }
>  }
> ```

**EDITED:**

You check out the below links to show all video file stored in your sd card in a listview.

1) [Link 1](http://gypsynight.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/how-to-show-all-video-file-stored-in-your-sd-card-in-a-listview/)
2) [Link 2](http://z4android.blogspot.in/2011/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html)
3) [Link 3](http://raghumudem.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-populating-music-files-from.html)

I hope it will help you .

Thanks.

Comment: k got it and thanks for it :)........ can you tell me how to create audio video player in which we can take all the songs from the device like folder or in subfolder and show it on listview also..!!

Comment: In your answer 1 fullsongpath is a class or an object??

Comment: same in this way if we want video song list and on select item song we want to play a video song then how it can be done?????