# Android: How to open an activity from a listview based on the extension of the file

Tags: android, file, listview

I have been busy with school and all that and currently working on an android multimedia app i'd like to use. i created a list and was able to filter the files on the sdcard (both .mp3s and .mp4s) but i have a problem. i want the app to launch activities i created (HomeaudioActivity, which deals with .mp3 files and HomevideoActivity, which deals with video files) when selected from the list (i created a class and called it "AllMediaActivity". in this activity, the whole media files have been pulled from the sdcard) based on its extension.

please i'm confused at this, i wrote some codes and i'm stuck at somewhere. below is the code with the issue, please where did i go wrong?

```
package com.src.imagine.playmedia;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity;

    public class AllPlayListActivity extends SherlockListActivity {
        // All the lists
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aMediaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Intent in;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aMediaListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        AllMediaManager amm = new AllMediaManager();
        // getting all the songs from sdcard
        this.aMediaList = amm.getPlayList();

        // lopping through the playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < aMediaList.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> media = aMediaList.get(i);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        aMediaListData.add(media);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aMediaListData,
        R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "mediaTitle" },
        new int[] { R.id.songTitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        // getting listitem index
        final int mediaIndex = position;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        if (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3")) {

        // Starting new intent
        in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeAudioActivity.class);
            // Sending mediaIndex to the audioPlayerActivity
        in.putExtra("songIndex", mediaIndex);
        setResult(100, in);
        // closing playlistview
        finish();
        } else if (name.endsWith(".mp4")
        || name.endsWith(".MP4")
        || name.endsWith(".h.264 avc")
        || name.endsWith(".H.264 AVC")
        || name.endsWith(".h.263")
        || name.endsWith(".H.263")
        || name.endsWith(".mpeg-4 sp")
        || name.endsWith(".MPEG-4 SP")
        || name.endsWith(".mpeg-4")
        || name.endsWith(".MPEG-4")
        || name.endsWith(".vp8")
        || name.endsWith(".VP8")) {
        // Starting new Intent
        in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeVideoActivity.class);
        // Sending mediaIndex to the videoPlayerActivity
        in.putExtra("videoIndex", mediaIndex);
        setResult(100, in);
        // closing playlistView
        finish();
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Unsupported video format",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
        }
        }

        }
        });

        }
            }
```

Comment: Are you calling this `Activity` with `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: The thing is this, i am confused at the onItemClick() method area. did i write the right code if i am to achieve what i want to achieve? i'm sorry for not indicating where i was having the problem. i tried converting the position to string but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-file-with-default-application-using-intents

google -> "android open file in default application" -> this post.

might help.

Answer (score 0):

You have written FileExtensionFilter class that has never been used. I am not sure if you are getting all media list.

You may refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784935/null-pointer-exception-in-song-manager) for further details.

Comment: When i was trying it out, it didn't work that was why i put that "unused" among it and when i remove it, it still doesn't work. Please is there something i'm not getting right here?