# NullPointerException in music player

Tags: android

Iam trying to build a musicplayer from the tutorial @AndroidHive.com. The code has no errors but when i run this app in mobile getting an error like this:

```
[.814: I/ActivityManager(1019): Start proc com.examplesample for activity com.examplesample/.MainActivity: pid=31113 uid=10119 gids={50119}
09-08 12:12:39.821: D/dalvikvm(31113): Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-08 12:12:39.963: D/dalvikvm(31113): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 2% free 9431K/9552K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
09-08 12:12:39.973: D/AndroidRuntime(31113): Shutting down VM
09-08 12:12:39.973: W/dalvikvm(31113): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415b4ba8)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113): Process: com.examplesample, PID: 31113
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.examplesample/com.examplesample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.examplesample.SongsManager.getPlayList(SongsManager.java:21)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.examplesample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
09-08 12:12:39.974: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    ... 11 more
09-08 12:12:39.977: W/ActivityManager(1019):   Force finishing activity com.examplesample/.MainActivity
09-08 12:12:40.086: D/dalvikvm(1019): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2662K, 21% free 30433K/38356K, paused 92ms, total 93ms]
```

mainactivity is:

```
package com.examplesample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements                 OnCompletionListener,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnBackward;
private ImageButton btnNext;
private ImageButton btnPrevious;
private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
private ImageButton btnRepeat;
private ImageButton btnShuffle;
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private Handler mhandler=new Handler();
private SongsManager SongsManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime=5000;
private int seekBackwardTime=5000;
private int currentSongIndex=0;
private boolean isShuffle=false;
private boolean isRepeat=false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> songsList=new     ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    btnPlay=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnForward=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnBackward=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnNext=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnPrevious=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPlaylist=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
    btnRepeat=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    btnShuffle=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
    songProgressBar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songCurrentDurationLabel=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    SongsManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    songsList=SongsManager.getPlayList();
    playSong(0);

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                if (mp!=null) {
                    mp.pause();
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);

                }
            }else{


            if(mp!=null){
                mp.start();
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
            }
            }
        }
    });
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int currentPosition=mp.getCurrentPosition();
            if(currentPosition+seekForwardTime<=mp.getDuration()){
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition+seekForwardTime);
            }else {
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }


        }
    });

    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int currentPosition=mp.getCurrentPosition();
            if(currentPosition-seekBackwardTime>=0){
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition-seekBackwardTime);
            }else {
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }

        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(currentSongIndex<(songsList.size()-1)){
            playSong(currentSongIndex+1);
            currentSongIndex=currentSongIndex+1;
        }else{
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex=0;
        }

        }
    });


    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(currentSongIndex>0){
                playSong(currentSongIndex-1);
                currentSongIndex=currentSongIndex-1;
            }else{
                playSong(songsList.size()-1);
                currentSongIndex=songsList.size()-1;
            }


        }
    });

    btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isRepeat){
                isRepeat=false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            } else{
                isRepeat=true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isShuffle=false;
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_all);
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }


        }
    });

    btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isShuffle){
                isShuffle=false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            } else {
                isShuffle=true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isRepeat=false;
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_all);
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }
        }
    });

    btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);    
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==100){
        currentSongIndex=data.getExtras().getInt("SongIndex");
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }
}


public void playSong(int songIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        mp.reset();

        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        String songTitle=songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setProgress(100);
        updateProgressBar();


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void updateProgressBar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mhandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask=new Runnable() {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long totalDuration=mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration=mp.getCurrentPosition();
        songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
        int progress=(int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration,totalDuration));
        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
        mhandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mhandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}


@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mhandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration=mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition=utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(),totalDuration);
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
    updateProgressBar();
}


@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(isRepeat) {
        playSong(currentSongIndex);

    } else if(isShuffle) {
        Random rand=new Random();
        currentSongIndex=rand.nextInt((songsList.size()-1)-0+1)+0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);

    }else {
        if(currentSongIndex<(songsList.size()-1)) {
            playSong(currentSongIndex+1);
            currentSongIndex=currentSongIndex+1;
        } else{
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex=0;

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();``
    mp.release();
}

}
```

When double click on the error it focuses at: 'songsList=SongsManager.getPlayList();
        playSong(0);'

Iam new to Android. I have only some knowledge about java.Any one help me please

songsmanager:

```
    public class SongsManager {
private long id;
private String title;
private String artist;
final String MEDIA_PATH=new String("/sdcard/");
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList=new   ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

public SongsManager(){

}
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File home=new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        if(home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length>0){
        for(File file:home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())){
            HashMap<String, String> song=new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0,      (file.getName().length()-4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
            songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        return songsList;
    }

    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {


    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return (name.endsWith(".mp3")||name.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: check you MainActivity.java:77 this line which content have?

Comment: Please, write down what's in line 77 in `MainActivity`

Comment: Also show `SongsManager` class code

Comment: Line number SongsManager.21?

Comment: @sunil The error is actually at line 21 in SongsManager, not in MainActivity.

Comment: reffer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14784935/3326331) same song manager returning null

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes you correct

Comment: You need to dig one level deeper into your SongsManager class. Something inside `getPlayList()` is causing the error. Also `SongsManager.getPlayList()` looks like you are calling a static method with a class name. However, you also have a variable named `SongsManager`. You should start variable names with lower case.

Comment: What's Line number SongsManager.21?

Comment: This line is the reason of `NullPointerException`

=> `SongsManager.getPlayList();`